# Is there a common method for importing javascript files in a similar way to css's @import?

Tags: javascript, import, compression, minify

Is there a common/standard way of including JavaScript files into the page that works in a similar way to the `@import` statement in CSS?

Specifically, I'm looking to end up with something similar to the following in the head of my HTML docs:

```
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="imports.css" />
    <script type="javascript" src="imports.js" />
</html>
```

So only one file is called from the HTML, but that file then has a list of files it needs to include, eg:

```
/* imports.css */
@import url('foo.css');  
@import url('bar.css');
```

and then something like this in javascript:

```
// import.js
import('jquery.js');
import('my.plugin.jquery.js');
import('my-code.js');
```

What I'm hoping to achieve is to have a single "call" from the HTML for the CSS and JS so that I can develop locally with many files and later combine/minify/gzip all css/js files into the respective `import.ext` file during deployment for performance.

What I **don't** want to do is have application code (PHP in this instance) change the HTML output for me; I need this to be completely client-side.

Suggestions?

Comment: You may want to look into [LabJS](http://labjs.com) or something else like that, but be aware that dynamically loading scripts will introduce interesting synchronization issues.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try creating and appending scripts. But I am not sure if that is what you 're after performance wise, since it will make as many requests as the number of files plus add the overhead of creating and appending elements.

```
var myScript = document.createElement("script");
myScript.src = "/js/test.js";
myScript.type= "text/javascript";

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(myScript);
```

or you can try something like this
http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/mk/